# PHPexcel get the data from another sheet and display it on activeSheet

Tags: javascript, php, phpexcel

I am attempting to display a set of data from a excel sheet using `PHPExcel` which has a name of `sheet1` but the reference data is located on `sheet2` i got an output of #REF! which i only see on excel if the formula is wrong or the data is missing.

So a got a hint that this is because i am referencing only at `sheet1` and the formula cannot get the data from `sheet2` is there a away to get the data from the other `sheet`?

Or just to be simple just disregard the formula and display the output as a plain text.

```
require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileType = 'Excel5'; 
$inputFileName = './data/myExcelData.xls'; 
$sheetname = 'Sheet1'; 

/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/ 
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType); 
/**  Advise the Reader of which WorkSheets we want to load  **/ 
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname); 
/**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/ 
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName); 


$myDataArray = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:K31' ,NULL, FALSE, TRUE, false);
```

I set the calculateFormula as FALSE to see the formula my `sheet2` name is ML

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't see data from a second sheet if you don't actually load that second sheet....

```
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
```

PHPExcel doesn't have a magical, telepathic link that allows it to see what's on `sheet2` if you've told it to load only `sheet1`.... load `sheet2` as well if you expect PHPExcel to calculate formula values that reference `sheet2`